# HP DeskJet 2778 All-in-One Ink Advantage Wireless Colour Printer not working

Tags: lubuntu, printing, hp, scanner, hplip

I bought **HP DeskJet 2778 All-in-One Ink Advantage Wireless Colour Printer** and unfortunately it is not working well with Lubuntu.

I have installed **HPLIP 3.20.X** but the printer is not being recognised well, at least through the HPLIP interface. Somehow can manage to print if I ask Lubuntu to recognise it as some other model but **Scanning is just not possible**. Can any one please help me to install this printer properly. I will prefer if I can use the USB interface only and avoid the wireless connection between the printer and the Lubuntu computer.

I used **hp-plugin** and **hp-doctor** commands but nothing worked.

**hp-plugin** : It tried looking for plugin and then looked for some authentication KEY. Said could not download the KEY. I asked it to proceed without it. Then it asked for root password. After entering that it gave an error :

**error : Python gobject/dbus may be not installed**

**error : Plug-in install failed**

I tried installing what ever I could find relevant but nothing worked.

Comment: Which release of Lubuntu are you asking about? and it's best if you copy & paste the actual command & particularly error messages into your question (tagged as code {})  as *some authentication key* is vague and I'm unsure if it's asking about a package, source or another type of key without specific message.

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04. The output of that command was not easy to capture. I had to take screen shots and then type them out. First of all it was a very long text that was scrolling in the terminal and then towards the end it refreshed the screen, that is how I felt, if I am not wrong.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/exzOy.png

Comment: If you're using a terminal on your Lubuntu desktop (LXDE), you should be able to copy & paste the text from the window (including scrolling back whatever the scroll-back allows; I think 1000 lines is the default).  I don't know the command that led to the output your pasted a screenshot to (text beats picture; as I can copy text from your question in looking up clues for you; I can't do that from pictures of text).

Comment: I got the text shown in that picture, when I used the command **hp-plugin**. I will try and check if I can copy the output. I know it can be done but this time it seems to be creating a bit of trouble.

Comment: Was not possible to post that entire length of code here as comment so have posted it as a reply.

Comment: You don't add additional details as comment; you can edit your own questions and add it there (formatting is better for Questions & Answers), but you've now answered this question yourself I see (which is likely not your intent; but it's how the site has treated the *answer* you provided).  This isn't a forum, but a Q&A site.

Comment: Sorry, I am more used to forums. So in this kind of place do we keep writing only as comments and keep editing the first post ?  :) Sorry for my ignorance. Actually I find it very difficult writing things in that comment box. There are no formatting options. Also is there anything worth noting in that terminal output that I posted ?

Answer (score 0):

```
hp-plugin

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.11)
Plugin Download and Install Utility ver. 2.1

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.


HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.11)
Plugin Download and Install Utility ver. 2.1

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.


(python3:1449): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 08:12:56.838: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(python3:1449): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 08:12:56.838: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(python3:1449): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 08:12:56.838: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
Checking for network connection...
Downloading plug-in from: 
Receiving digital keys: /usr/bin/gpg --homedir /home/hontra/.hplip/.gnupg --no-permission-warning --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 0x4ABA2F66DBD5A99894990E0673D770CDA59047B9
-^Creating directory plugin_tmp
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing HPLIP 3.20.11 Plugin Self Extracting Archive..............................................................

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.11)
Plugin Installer ver. 3.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Plug-in version: 3.20.11
Installed HPLIP version: 3.20.11
Number of files to install: 64


(python3:1804): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 18:56:11.307: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(python3:1804): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 18:56:11.307: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(python3:1804): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 18:56:11.307: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
Plugin installation failed
error: Python gobject/dbus may be not installed
error: Plug-in install failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

HP 2778 AIO printer needs some extra work to get it do wireless printing & scans. I have answered it here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1440601/314168