# HP 2778 Wireless printer - cannot add this printer in Ubuntu 22.10 wirelessly. hp-setup freezes

Tags: printing, hp, hplip, wifi-direct

[image]I recently bought a HP Deskjet 2778 AIO printer. It works well in Windows laptop as well as from android phones. But, when I tried to add this printer for wireless printing in Ubuntu 22.10, the hp-setup lists the printer and the gui freezes with some error message telling to check firewall rules. How to setup this printer?
Note: latest hplip  3.22.6+dfsg0-1 is installed.

**EDIT**: I have answered with the solution to get this printer working in Linux below.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried adding the printer with USB connected. The printer is detected, but USB I/O error message pops up. Cannot add.  [image]

This is when I added the printer as USB printer: [image]

Comment: Give the output of `driverless`.

Comment: @brian_p: I added the 2778 printer after connecting using WiFi-direct and then ran settings>add printer which detected the model. Until now, I was expecting hp-setup to configure this printer which, unfortunately it cannot seems to do. I have updated the post with the screenshots hplip is throwing up.

Comment: If you execute `avahi-browse -tr _ipp._tcp` and `avahi-browse -tr _ipps._tcp` on the terminal what do you see?  This checks that at the least the printer is seen by the avahi daemon which is used by cups to install a new printer. You might not even  need hplip if the printer is detected by avahi. It depends whether your printer supports ipp, but most likely it does.

Comment: The output of `lpinfo -v` will also be useful. If you see a device URI with the protocol `ipp` or `dnssd` then you should be fine. If you see one of these, I would purge hplip and directly install the printer at Settings->Printers or at the cups web admin interface `http://127.0.0.1:631/`

Comment: Just for the info. Just to  check, I reinstalled ubuntu 22.10 from scratch and immediately purged hplip. The printer, which was connected to the WIFI network, could still be discovered and installed at 127.0.0.1:631. One difficulty: if I went to Administration->Find new printers, none were seen, because I was not authenticated. I add to first do Administration->Add printer to login with my system user id, then not proceeding ahead with Add printer and go back to Administration->Find new printers, instead.

Comment: You do not have to login as root, better not to actually, but the user that logins must be in the `lpadmin` group or the `root` group. You are if you installed ubuntu. You can check with `id $USER` in a terminal.

Comment: I have updated the post. There is an USB I/O error despite the printer getting detected.

Comment: That may be a different problem. You should be able to install your printer using a wireless connection. What are the outputs of `driverless` , of `avahi-browse -tr _ipp._tcp` and of `avahi-browse -tr _ipps._tcp` in a terminal?

Comment: It says `wireless capable device found`. So you do not need a usb connection. Maybe hplip requires a usb connection, but most likely, as it is the case with most printers, you do not need a driver, so you could purge hplip and install directly at Settings->Printers.

Comment: Your printer is listed here https://openprinting.github.io/printers/ as accepting the driverless technology.  This means that you do not need hplip.

Comment: I purged hplip and added the printer - But, it is added as CUPS-BRF-Printer. It is not seeing the printer model.

Comment: Please, again,  give the output of `driverless` , of `avahi-browse -tr _ipp._tcp`  and of `avahi-browse -tr _ipps._tcp` in a terminal. This will tell us what can be installed using the current network connection. If `Settings->Printers` only see `CUPS-BRF-Printer`, then your printer is not seen. Maybe at the time you did not have your wireless connection.

Comment: Or may be the printer is not configured to broadcast itself on the local network.  That's why we need to see the output of these commands. You might need to turn on the ipp feature using the interface provided directly on the printer. It should be on  by default, but maybe in your case it is not.

Comment: @Dominic108: I connected the WiFi printer using WiFi. (Default password is given). And, ran the commands you have asked to run.  `:~# driverless
ipps://HP%20DeskJet%202700%20series%20%5BD0D3BA%5D._ipps._tcp.local/` The other command output is too long. I've put it on https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/RJTnYnDRzy/

Comment: Scan also works, if I connect with the WiFi password.

Comment: You did not give the output of `avahi-browse -tr _ipp._tcp`. Is it because it's empty. If it is empty, it means that only ipps is enabled, not ipp. In your local network, you should not need ipps. If you use ipps, the problem might be authentication. If you go to your printer interface, you might be able to enable ipp instead of ipps.

Comment: BTW, `avahi-browse -t _ipp._tcp` without the `r` would have been enough for our purpose.

Comment: Also, now that I see the output, I see that you might be able  to configure your printer using your browser by using  `HPA8B13BD0D3BA.local` or  `192.168.223.1` in the url bar. You might have to accept the certificate the first time you visit the printer web interface. This cannot be used to configure your computer, but it can be used to enable ipp instead of ipps.

Comment: If you get access to the printer web interface and see a  section networking, ideally a section advanced networking, then a screenshot of the options available will be useful. You need to enable Bonjour, if presented as an option, and IPP.

Comment: Hi @Dominic108 I have ran the commands and the output is attached here: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/SFZ9jqJDwf/  Screenshots of the admin page of the printers are here: https://ibb.co/XfBDqJD
https://ibb.co/vh9HTP8

Comment: OK, so you have the ipp connection to the printer. Normally, after you click on `Add Printer ...` on the top bar  in `Settings->Printers` you should see your model announced as one choice. You need to click on it to add it and then you can edit it with `Additional Printer Settings ....`. Click on `Change` for the Device URI. The device URI that  you must pick should be found in the section `Network Printer`. Pick the one that says `IPP Network printer via DNS-SD`

Comment: if you do not see your printer model as a choice, then on printer web interface, click on `Network` in the black top bar and show a screenshot and do the same for `Settings`. You need to find where you can adjust the settings for the network. Maybe some feature needs to be enabled (or disabled)

Comment: Without connecting to WiFi-direct, only Braille device (CUPS-BRF-Printer) is listed. I tried searching while connected to printer via WiFi and it shows an entry with _ipps_tcp.local and have added it. But, no "Additional Printer settings" available. Below is the WiFi search listing : https://i.ibb.co/L6NrKQm/Screenshot-from-2022-11-11-10-13-26.png

Comment: Both choices, the one with the ipps below or the one without it,  might work, but I would use the one without the ipps below. You can choose the device uri yourself. Once you added the printer by cllicking on it, then you can go back on the main `Settings->Printers` window and click on `Additional Printer Settings`  to pick the device uri as I explained above.

Comment: @Dominic108 Sorry for the late responses. I finally got the printer configured, after you pointing lead to the web configuration> Network. I first connected to printer via WiFi-direct and accessed the web admin page HPAxxBA.local . The printer was already configured  for the WiFi point in another room. So, I used the network> wireless setup wizard to connect to my current WiFi (internet). Now, I disconnected WiFi-direct connection to printer and added printer from settings. . I am going to write an answer here, hoping this will be helpful. And,  Thank You dear Dominic108 for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Special thanks to @Dominic105 who guided me to the solution*

This solution *may* work for most of the HP WiFi AIO printers.

HP 2778 AIO WiFi printer is not getting configured using hplip (hp's driver) and also through settings>printer>add printer. On context is, this printer is already configured with another WiFi network. So, now the printer is in new WiFi network, which needs to be added to the printer.

What worked is,

- First connect the printer to PC via WiFi-direct. WiFi-Direct password can be printed out by pressing Information button in the printer.
- Access the web URL or IP of the printer. In my case, it is 192.168.0.206 or HPAxxBA.local listed in the web settings page. The IP information can be printed out by pressing printer information button on the printer panel. To gain administrative privilage, you need to give the printer pin which is found on the door of the printer cartridge compartment, which will allow full access.
- Go to Wireless Setup Wizard and add your WiFi network to the printer.
- Remove WiFi-Direct connection between Printer and PC and forget the connection.
- Now, Go to Settings>Printer>Add Printer. It will search and list the available printers now. Select the simple option - **HP 2700 series**.
  The option can be confirmed by checking the device URI for **`"_ipp._tcp.local"`**.
- I have hplip also installed, in case if it helps.

That's it. Now, printer works well in WiFi as well as you can use *simple scan* for scanning purposes.

[image]

[image]

Simple scan detected HP 2778 AIO printer:
[image]

Comment: I worked hard to explain how you can avoid using hplip specific drivers. I suspect that you felt this was sub-optimal, because it did not use the driver specifically written for the printer. It's my mistake. I should have better explained that it is the opposite. It's better to use the driverless technology.  I am sorry about that.

Comment: You should go back to `Settings->Printers` then cllick on `Additional Printer Settings ...` and select the ipp device uri in the section Network Printers. You will get all the features, scan, ink level, etc., because it's all standardized. In the future, Ubuntu will not support drivers specific to a printer model.

Comment: Thank you @Dominic108 for the insights. I always assumed HPLIP will have the better driver for recent printers. Anyways, I removed the printer and added it again, with ipp printer as default with driverless. Unfortunately, no ink level warnings available for this printer. The printer list also always shows the printer as HP_Deskjet_2700_DOD3BA along with the ipp option I've selected as default.  
Screenshots:  
printer settings with driverless:
https://ibb.co/XXX9pNN 

Ink level not reporting:
https://ibb.co/GM6Wg99

system-config-printer:
https://ibb.co/4f8XzX3

Comment: You should see the ink levels. It's  very unlikely that your printer does not send the info. You need to have printed one document. The ink levels are only set/updated after you print a document. It's also possible that you do not use the correct device uri. Please show a screenshot of the window for the `Settings` tab of  `Additional Printer Settings` for the printer connection that says driverless. This window shows `Description:`, `Location:`,  `Device URI`, ... The device URI should start with `dnssd:` though `ipp:` might also work.

Comment: Also, visit `http://localhost:631/admin` go to the `Administration` tab and click on `Add Printer`, enter your system credential (the one that is in the `lpadmin`  group - you are if you installed ubuntu), but do not proceed ahead. This is just to enter your credential. Then go back to `Administration`  and click on `Manage Printers` and then on the printer and give a screenshot of the window.

Comment: Also, you should check the driver. The term "driverless" is a bit of a misnomer. All devices need a driver. "Driverless" refers to a standard. but you want to setup that standard in accordance with your printer. The name of the driver should contain your printer model as well as "driverless".

Comment: @Dominic108: I ran settings>printers>printer details and clicked "Search for Drivers" and it did. After that, the ink levels are showing. I went to CUPS  web admin page and the result showed printer is using Driver: "HP DeskJet 2700 series, driverless, cups-filters 1.28.16 (color)". However, the printer settings only shows "HP Deskjet 2700 series, driverless". I hope it is OK, since the ink levels are showing now.  Screenshots:
ink levels showing:
https://ibb.co/mNrk83Z

printer drivers available:
https://ibb.co/pL2jV1P

CUPS admin page > Manage Printers:
https://ibb.co/Qbgfk3g

Comment: Is there a way to get HP's color profile available for this printer? Can I extract it from Windows driver. Thanks for the continuous guiding. I will update the answer to use CUPS driver instead of hplip.

Comment: I am not sure what would be the point of managing the color profile through the driver.  I am not expert in management of color profiles, but I have the impression it is something managed at the application level and it's complicated and requires special instruments.

Comment: @Dominic108 I have a Debian testing (bookworm) also installed on this PC. But, ink levels are not showing. I configured it as it is on Ubuntu 22.10. It even uses the same cups-filter-1.28.16. Any idea if any packages are missing.